# Adding constraint to auto generate Uniqueidentifier in MSSQL with EF6 fails

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using code first approach to generate migrations for existing database. My (simplified) entity in C# looks like this

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Subject { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then the configuration was like this

```
HasKey(c => c.Id)
        .Property(c => c.Id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

Property(c => c.Subject)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
        .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute {IsUnique = true}));

Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
```

---

The Subject property has been updated in similar way, and it works correctly. The generated SQL script from EF was like this (also simplified as that migration contained more changes in DB model. It is missing MigrationHistory Insert statement, I've excluded it as it is too big.):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = N'IX_Subject' AND object_id = object_id(N'[dbo].[User]', N'U'))
    DROP INDEX [IX_Subject] ON [dbo].[User]
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.User.Subject', @newname = N'Subject_Old', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] ADD [Subject] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT newsequentialid()
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_Subject] ON [dbo].[User]([Subject])
DECLARE @var91 nvarchar(128)
SELECT @var91 = name
FROM sys.default_constraints
WHERE parent_object_id = object_id(N'dbo.User')
AND col_name(parent_object_id, parent_column_id) = 'Subject_Old';
IF @var91 IS NOT NULL
    EXECUTE('ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var91 + ']')
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] DROP COLUMN [Subject_Old]
```

---

So I changed DatabaseGeneratedOption.**None** to **Identity**.

```
HasKey(c => c.Id)
    .Property(c => c.Id)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

And generated migration:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.User");
    AlterColumn("dbo.User", "Id", c => c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true));
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.User", "Id");
}    
public override void Down()
{
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.User");
    AlterColumn("dbo.User", "Id", c => c.Guid(nullable: false));
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.User", "Id");
}
```

But when updating database I'm not getting constraint with default value as I've got on Subject's property, It seems that in generated SQL script is missing **DEFAULT newsequentialid()**. Here's the script (also INSERT statement is not included):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.User]
DECLARE @var0 nvarchar(128)
SELECT @var0 = name
FROM sys.default_constraints
WHERE parent_object_id = object_id(N'dbo.User')
AND col_name(parent_object_id, parent_column_id) = 'Id';
IF @var0 IS NOT NULL
EXECUTE('ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var0 + ']')
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] ALTER COLUMN [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.User] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
```

The User's Id is not referenced anywhere as FK. 
I've got EntityFramework 6 and MSSQL server express 14. 
I've tried to use attribute annotation, but the result is the same.
My question is: What am I doing wrong or is this an EntityFramework's bug?